# How to add a 'total' dataframe to a dictionary of dataframes in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am a beginner, so feedback is welcome.

I have a dictionary of data frames, with each value of the dictionary a data frame containing data from a specific country.  I'd like to create a **total** data frame, that shows the sum of each of the data frames in the dictionary.

```
d['total'] = d['Germany'].add(d['Belgium'], fill_value=0)
d['total'] = d['total'].add(d['France'], fill_value=0)
```

This works perfectly fine for two dataframes, but I have `n` number of dataframes in my dictionary, so I thought it was stupid to repeat this for each country. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To sum all existing DataFrames in the dictionary, you can use:

```
d['total'] = sum(d.values())
```

Or to limit to a list of keys:

```
l = ['Germany', 'Belgium', 'France']

d['total'] = sum(d[c] for c in l)
```

##### using only numeric columns:

```
d['total'] = sum(d[c].select_dtypes('number') for c in l)
```

Comment: Yes this is correct.  Thank you!! 
As a note for others, this method doesn't work if there are strings in your dateframe.  I did, and this broke until I removed the columns with strings.

Comment: @stevearama111 in this case use `select_dtypes('number')` to filter the numeric columns, see update

Comment: you're a champion.  thanks!